# Javascript: Array of Objects is returning undefined when accessing to a single Element. Even though there are 696 Objects saved in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I am a beginner when it comes to Javascript, so I am already sorry if this question is a bit obvious. So my exercise consisted in holding information from a csv File with the help of d3. after that I just want to display the first Element of that array.

When I perform `console.log(editedData)` it Appears in the console an array with 696 elements `Array(696)` but when I try to perform `console.log(editedData[0])` the console displays `undefined`. At first I thought this behaviour occurs due to a conflict in the synchronisation but after using Promises I still get the same results...

```js
const editedData = [];

const organizedData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    d3.csv("testData.csv").then(function(data){
      data.map( element => {
        const dateAndTime = element.date.split(" ");
        const dataBlock = {
          date: dateAndTime[0],
          time: dateAndTime[1],
          testInfo: element.info1,
          testInfo2: element.info2,
          testInfo3: element.info3
        }
        editedData.push(dataBlock);
      });
    });
    resolve();
  });
}

const diplayData = () => {
  //console.log(editedData) ==> Array(696)
  //console.log(editedData) ==> undefined
  console.log(editedData[0]);
}

organizeData().then(displayData());
```

Can somebody help me with this issue? I am wondering why is this problem happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the the parenthesis from `displayData()`, you're calling the function immediately before the promise is fullfilled.

Comment: I tried but I still get `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You need to call resolve inside the d3.csv then function.. just after the data.map function

Comment: Thank you! that solved the problem :) I think I get now what was the problem. If it is not inside the `.then` function, the "chain" process is being interrupted, right?

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.resolve()` must have resultant value.

```
const editedData = [];

const organizedData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    d3.csv("testData.csv").then(function(data){
      data.map( element => {
        const dateAndTime = element.date.split(" ");
        const dataBlock = {
          date: dateAndTime[0],
          time: dateAndTime[1],
          testInfo: element.info1,
          testInfo2: element.info2,
          testInfo3: element.info3
        }
        editedData.push(dataBlock);
      });
    });
    resolve(editedData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh, I thought `Problem.resolve`, was just like a permission to proceed to the function inside the `.then`. It worked without the resultant value, but why should I put the value inside?

Comment: How your function will come to know which value has to return? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve